# How can i use in array in the vuetify?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

The array items are not rendering in the right columns for the following code:

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-simple-table>
      <template v-slot:default>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-left">Mon </th>
            <th class="text-left">Tue</th>
            <th class="text-left">Wed </th>
            <th class="text-left">Thu</th>
            <th class="text-left">Fri </th>
            <th class="text-left">Sat </th>
            <th class="text-left">Sun</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <template v-for="item in schedules">
              <td v-if="days.includes(item.day)" class="text-left">{{item.from_time}}-{{item.to_time}}</td>
              <td v-else class="text-left">-</td>
            </template>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </template>
    </v-simple-table>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    schedules: [
      { day: 1, from_time: '15:00', to_time: '13:00' },
      { day: 6, from_time: '16:00', to_time: '16:30' },
    ],
    days: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
  })
})
</script>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/GRRoaWd)

The second item in `schedules` (day 6) should be placed in column **Sat**, not column **Tue**.

Note:

- If index day of schedules = 1, the time placed in column **Mon**
- If index day of schedules = 2, the time placed in column **Tue**
- If index day of schedules = 3, the time placed in column **Wed**

and so on...

How can I render `schedules` items in the weekday columns by their day index? Maybe the solution is to combine `schedules` and `days` to be one data object.

Answer (score 1):

You were only iterating over the schedules array in your template and therefore only rendered two cells in your table body.

I updated the template and script code to get the expected output.

template code:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-simple-table>
     <template v-slot:default>
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th class="text-left">Mon </th>
           <th class="text-left">Tue</th>
           <th class="text-left">Wed </th>
           <th class="text-left">Thu</th>
           <th class="text-left">Fri </th>
           <th class="text-left">Sat </th>
           <th class="text-left">Sun</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>

           <template v-for="dayEntry in days">
                  <td v-if="getScheduleByDay(dayEntry)" class="text-left">{{getScheduleByDay(dayEntry).from_time}}-{{getScheduleByDay(dayEntry).to_time}}</td>
                  <td v-else class="text-left">-</td> 
           </template>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </template>
  </v-simple-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

script code:

```
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data: () => ({
      schedules: [
        { day: 1, from_time: '15:00', to_time: '13:00' },
        { day: 6, from_time: '16:00', to_time: '16:30' },
      ],
      days: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    }),
    methods: {
      getScheduleByDay(dayEntry) {
        console.log(dayEntry)
        const relevantDay = this.schedules.filter(entry => entry.day === dayEntry);
        if(relevantDay.length > 0)
          return relevantDay[0];
        return null;
      }
    }
  })
```

See also the updated code pen: 
https://codepen.io/simonthiel2/pen/Rwwrzav

Comment: thanks. but is there another way? for example combining scheduled and days into 1 data. after that display the combined data. but the combined data is using script

Answer (score 0):

In your original code:

```html
<template v-for="item in schedules">
  <td v-if="days.includes(item.day)" class="text-left">{{item.from_time}}-{{item.to_time}}</td>
  <td v-else class="text-left">-</td>
</template>
```

There are a couple issues:

1. You're iterating only `schedules`, which could be fewer than the number of days in a week (as is the case in your example).
2. The `v-if` checks if `days` includes the item's day number, which will likely be true (assuming your data always fits the domain), so this effectively makes the table render all the `schedules` items in order.

One solution is to use `Array.prototype.map` on `days` (i.e., the array of day IDs that `schedules[].day` maps to) in a computed prop:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    weekly() {
      return this.days.map(day => this.schedules.find(s => s.day == day))
    }
  }
}
```

...and update your template to use that prop:

```html
<template v-for="item in weekly">
  <td v-if="item" class="text-left">{{item.from_time}}-{{item.to_time}}</td>
  <td v-else class="text-left">-</td>
</template>
```

[updated codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ZEEQdoa)

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to combine these both data,you can do it like this,it is completely work well

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: () => ({
      schedules: [
        { day: 1, from_time: '15:00', to_time: '13:00' },
        { day: 6, from_time: '16:00', to_time: '16:30' },
      ],
      days: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
      weekday:[]
    }),
    created(){
      for(let i = 0; i < this.days.length;i++){
        var obj = null
        for(let j = 0; j < this.schedules.length; j++){
          if(this.days[i] === this.schedules[j].day){
            obj = this.schedules[j]
            break
          }
        }
        this.weekday.push(obj)
      }
    },
    methods: {
      
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-simple-table>
     <template v-slot:default>
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th class="text-left">Mon </th>
           <th class="text-left">Tue</th>
           <th class="text-left">Wed </th>
           <th class="text-left">Thu</th>
           <th class="text-left">Fri </th>
           <th class="text-left">Sat </th>
           <th class="text-left">Sun</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>

           <template v-for="day in weekday">
                  <td v-if="day" class="text-left">{{day.from_time}}-{{day.to_time}}</td>
                  <td v-else class="text-left">-</td> 
           </template>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </template>
  </v-simple-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```